# UNLOADing file onto client system

Tags: sqlanywhere

I'm wondering how I would `UNLOAD` a file from a SQL Anywhere v10 database onto a client computer. I have multiple servers (30+) at different locations, this is the query I have been using to `UNLOAD` on a local server:

```
UNLOAD
SELECT tran, id, amount, date, collection, impacts, type
FROM transactions
ORDER BY tran_num
TO 'C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Clinic.txt' DELIMITED BY '|'
APPEND ON
QUOTES OFF
```

I'm looking to modify this to be able to unload from the remote servers but the file to generate at my local/client location where I am sending the query. I am using DtSQL to connect to the database remotely. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

share a folder on the client machine and then use the full network path to that client's folder in the unload statement.  like '\\targetPC\SharedFolder\Clinic.txt'

or

share a folder on the DB server and then copy the file to your target machine after the unload